# Dissassembe multiple objective C .o object files at once in IDAPro from archive

Tags: objective-c, automation, static-libraries, reverse-engineering, ida

I am trying to reverse engineer iOS static library files (".a" extension). Whenever I am trying to open it in IDAPro it gives me list of ".o" files in from the .a archive. My goal is to translate .o files to pseudocode using Hex Rays decompiler. It is taking so much to time to go through each object file in the list as shown in following image

[This is how it looks like when I have to select object files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vp4I.jpg) (i have to go through one by one and save its C code. )
Is there any command via command prompt or any way that can help me in decompiling all the object files at once.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: did you figure out how to disassemble all object files at once? I am stuck at this problem as well.